# Trying to load a Google Hangouts App with the developer API

Tags: google-api, google-hangouts

I'm trying to load a `Google Hangout` app using the example `XML` file from the developers API but it doesn't load.
It works when I load the basic API file.

Here is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<Module>
  <ModulePrefs title="MyApp">
    <Require feature="rpc"/>
    <Require feature="views"/>
  </ModulePrefs>
  <Content type="html">
    <![CDATA[
<script src="//plus.google.com/hangouts/_/api/dev/hangout.js"></script>
      <!-- Your application code -->
    ]]>
  </Content>
</Module>
```

Here is the error:

> There was an error loading your app!
>  
>   This app did not load because there appears to be something wrong with it.

I guess I'm missing something with the developer api settings in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unchecking the `Make your application available to all users` box solves the problem since apps running in the developer api mode are visible only to developers.